# Python 3.6.1 ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I'm still pretty new to python and i've been having some trouble getting modules to work. When ever i do something like this:

module.py:
   `def function():
    var = "this is some stuff"`

main.py:
   `import module`

But when i run main.py, i end up getting: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module'

EDIT: I probably should have mentioned this is in the original post, the files are in the same directory

Comment: Where is the module file located? Has to be in the same place as where you installed python otherwise you'd need to join the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import with from your local project path.

like if your project name is test,
app name is test1,and
test1 having module.py and main.py

you need to import like this

**from test.testing import module**

i hope this may help.